# What's the best practice for making an optionally editable text field in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

So I am trying to make an interaction which is similar to the file browser in VSCode.  I display a list of items, and click on an item to select it.  I want to then be able to press enter when an item is selected to make that item editable.

My first attempt was to use the `contentEditable` property, as it seemed the easy way to turn editing on and off on my div:

```
...
render(
    <div
      contentEditable={this.state.isEditable}>
      {this.state.text}
    </div>
)
```

But when I use this method, I get this warning:

> [Error] Warning: A component is `contentEditable` and contains `children` managed by React. It is now your responsibility to guarantee that none of those nodes are unexpectedly modified or duplicated. This is probably not intentional.

If I understand correctly, contentEditable is breaking the convention of React, and this may cause issues if I use this method.

As I have read more about `contentEditable` in general, I have also seen that there are some issues with the HTML generated inside being inconsistent across different browsers.

So my question is, what would be the standard/best practice to achieve something like this where I want to swap between a display-only element and an input element?  Should I use an input tag instead and disable it instead of enabling it?

Comment: Do you want HTML? Or just text (like the file browser in VSCode)?

Comment: That looks like a *call* to `render` with one argument, which would be unusual in React. (*You* don't call the component `render` function, React does; and the ReactDOM `render` function takes two arguments.)

Comment: You could just use an input field, and toggle the enabled/disabled flag, and potentially style the disabled version to look more like a normal text field if necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider using input's native attributes, readonly/disabled, depends on your use-case, for example:

```
<input readOnly={!this.state.isEditable}/>
```

Comment: Properly styled this could be a great way to go, good thought.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`contenteditable` will give you HTML, but you're not using `this.state.text` as HTML (just text), and as you've noted the HTML varies from browser to browser. I'd swap a styled `input` for the `div`:

```
return this.state.isEditable
    ? <input className="styling-class" type="text" value={this.state.text} />
    : <div>{this.state.text}</div>
;
```